# what is the name this java widget?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to find the java class name for this widget.  It looks like a bubble pop up when the user hovers the mouse on an item.  This widget is normally used to display a short description about the item.  You would often see this on the toolbar button when the mouse is on the button.  If anyone has used Qt, it would be similar to the QWhatsThis widget.  Is there an equivalent widget in java ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably a [Tool Tip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html), though it's difficult to say without seeing a screenshot.